# group subdocuments - angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, group-by

i have object value in JSON, within which it contains array.i am trying to group the subdocument but does not work. my [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y9ZjUTYZ78y5IFQmkx8g?p=preview)

The below is my controller code.
**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = {
"_id": "56c4758af801160e00d176e0",
"orderfood": [
{
"_id": "569d84f04834c10e003dff36",
"qty": "1",
"confirm": "placed",
"price": 125,
"name": "Paneer Tikka"
},
{
"_id": "569d869fff1fe20e00f8ba9b",
"qty": "1",
"confirm": "placed",
"price": 85,
"name": "Falooda"
},
{
"_id": "569d869fff1fe20e00f8ba9b",
"qty": "1",
"confirm": "placed",
"price": 85,
"name": "Falooda"
}
],
"title": "Status",
"created": "2016-02-17T13:28:42.226Z"
}
});
```

The below is my HTML code
**HTML**

```
<p ng-repeat="(key,value) in list.orderfood | groupBy:'name'">
  {{key}}
</p>
```

my [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y9ZjUTYZ78y5IFQmkx8g?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know what you want your ouput to be but you need to do this with a custom function:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Main">
    <div ng-repeat="list in itemsToFilter() | filter:filterNames">
        <b>{{list.name}}</b>
        <li ng-repeat="item in itemsToFilter() | filter: {name: list.name}">NAME: {{item.name}}- PRICE: {{item.price}}, etc...</li>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
function Main($scope) {
$scope.list = {
"_id": "56c4758af801160e00d176e0",
"orderfood": [
{
"_id": "569d84f04834c10e003dff36",
"qty": "1",
"confirm": "placed",
"price": 125,
"name": "Paneer Tikka"
},
{
"_id": "569d869fff1fe20e00f8ba9b",
"qty": "1",
"confirm": "placed",
"price": 85,
"name": "Falooda"
},
{
"_id": "569d869fff1fe20e00f8ba9b",
"qty": "1",
"confirm": "placed",
"price": 85,
"name": "Falooda"
}
],
"title": "Status",
"created": "2016-02-17T13:28:42.226Z"
}

var indexedTeams = [];

$scope.itemsToFilter = function() {
    indexedTeams = [];
    return $scope.list.orderfood;
}

$scope.filterNames = function(item) {
    var nameIsNew = indexedTeams.indexOf(item.name) == -1;
    if (nameIsNew) {
        indexedTeams.push(item.name);
    }

    return nameIsNew;
}
}
```

here is a link...[js-fiddle exmple: http://jsfiddle.net/L6cQN/305/](http://jsfiddle.net/L6cQN/305/)

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for